# Como puedo mejorar este codigo de Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Hola amigos estoy buscando mejorar este código el cual estoy usando con Python y Selenium ya que estoy ingresando a varias direcciones y según el tipo de equipo la contraseña que le voy a mandar es diferente, entonces lo primero que necesito es identificar ante que version del equipo me encuentro esto lo estoy haciendo con Try y Except para cuando uno falle intente con el otro XPATH pero creo que esta no es la mejor manera así que me gustaría escuchar sus sugerencias.

```
        try:
            verificador = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/blockquote/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td').text
            print(verificador)
            print('V1')

        except BaseException:
            try:
                verificador = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'login_title').text
                print(verificador)
                print('V2')

            except BaseException:
                try:
                    verificador = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ConfigForm"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]').text
                    print(verificador)
                    print('V3')

                except BaseException:
                    print("No se encontro la version")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer una estructura de datos (como un diccionario) con los xpaths e iterar en ella, si conecta en alguno, sales del ciclo:

```py
xpaths = {
    'V1':'/html/body/blockquote/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td', 
    'V2':'//*[@id="login_title"]',
    'V3':'//*[@id="ConfigForm"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]'
}

for ver, xpt in xpaths.items():
    try:
        version = ver
        verificador = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpt).text
        break
    except:
        verificador = False
```

Finalmente para evaluar qué xpath seleccionó:

```py
if verificador:
    print(verificador)
    print(version)
else:
    print('No se encontró la versión')
```